# New DataFrame column using the key of a dictionary as row value when one of it's values is found in a given row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hierarchy

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a large number of unique values. I would like to group these values with a more general column. By doing so I expect to add hierarchies to my data and thus make analysis easier.

One thing that worked was to copy the column and replaced the values as follows:

```
data.loc[data['new_col'].str.contains('string0|string1'), 'new_col']\
         = 'substitution'
```

However, I am trying to find a way to reproduce this easily without adding a condition for each entry.

Also tried using without success using the following methods:

- dict.items()
- pd.df.replace()
  Those attempts were futile for me.

I would like to hear your advice to know how to approach this.

```
import pandas as pd
# My DataFrame looks similar to this:
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'w', 'c', 'd', 'z']})

# The dictionary were I store the generalization:
>>> subs = {'g1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
...         'g2': ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']}

>>> df
   A  H
0  a  g1
1  w  g2
2  c  g1
3  d  g1
4  z  g2
```

Comment: You can show example  of output that you want?

Comment: Please fix your sample data

Answer (score 1):

create a new dict by swapping key with values of list. Next, map `df.A` with the swapped dict.

```
swap_dict = {x: k for k, v in d.items() for x in v}

Out[1054]:
{'a': 's1',
 'b': 's1',
 'c': 's1',
 'd': 's1',
 'w': 's2',
 'x': 's2',
 'y': 's2',
 'z': 's2'}

df['H'] = df.A.map(swap_dict)

Out[1058]:
   A   H
0  a  s1
1  w  s2
2  c  s1
3  d  s1
4  z  s2
```

---

**Note**: I directly use keys of your dict as values of `H` instead of `g1`, `g2`,.... because I think it is enough to identify each group of values. If you still want `g1`, `g2`,..., it is easy to accomplish. Just let me know.
*I also named your dict as `d` in my code*

Comment: I changed the name only on one part, but it's easy to understand what you do.
I was considering using to_frame > melt > map but your's it's more elegant.Thank you